# MalformedParameterizedTypeException with CDI on Java SE

Tags: java, cdi

I want to write a little Java SE based tool using CDI services from our business layer. I'll have to package everything using maven into a 'jar-with-.dependencies'.
To start small I want to see a simple example running. So I went for a simple example:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {

    Weld weld = new Weld();
    System.out.println("Weld constructed");
    WeldContainer initialize = weld.initialize();    // exception thrown
    System.out.println("Weld init");
    TestInject importConfigurationCommand = initialize.instance().select(TestInject.class).get();
    importConfigurationCommand.sayHello();
    weld.shutdown();
}
```

The Test inject class looks like this:

```
public class TestInject {

public void sayHello() {

    System.out.println("Hallo");
    }
}
```

I get the following exception when starting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
    at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.validate ConstructorArguments(Unknown Source)
```

What is the reason for this exception? Which parametrized type is it referring to?

Comment: Ooops, I forget to mention, that I use weld-se 2.3.5-final

Comment: What java version? What do your dependencies look like? If you have a sample project that can reproduce it.

Comment: I'm using JDK 8.
The complete project is rather complex (and proprietary). So I can't share the pom of the final project, which was used in the small code sample above. Problem seemed to be that dependencies from other parts (like different beans.xml) hindered deployment/packaging.
Unfortunately, I don't have a sample project and I can't extract it from the project code in reasonable time.
By cleaning up my POM and updating versions (e.g. weld to 2.3.5.final) I got past the MalformedParameterizedTypeException.But I don't understand what this MalformedParameterizedTypeException is all about.